# How to mock dao layer with the same methods in service layer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am kinda confuse how to test my dao layer which contain same method as my service layer. I managed to test my service layer and stuck figuring out how to test my dao layer.

```
@Repository
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
    
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @Override
    public Set<MyForm> findSomething(String title, String name, ZonedDateTime datetime) {
        String sql= "SELECT * from myTable WHERE title= :d_title AND name = :d_name AND mydatetime= :d_datetime";
                 
                  

                  
        SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("d_title", title)
                .addValue("d_name",name)
                .addValue("d_datetime",datetime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toOffsetDateTime());
        
        List<MyForm> myForm= template.query(sql, namedParameters, new MyRowMapper());
        Set<MyForm> setMyForm = new HashSet<MyForm>(myForm);
        return setMyForm ;
    }
```

Comment: A common approach is to mock repositories in Service tests, and to use a local, temporary db (in memory or in a docker container) for Repository tests

Comment: Hi, yes I did that to my service test. Tho I am confuse when it comes to my repository.  Anyway, thanks for this I will study it to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To test your datalayer you can make use of Spring Boots Testslice `DataJdbcTest`.

```
@DataJdbcTest
public class DaoImplIT {

    @Autowired
    private DaoImpl daoImpl;

    @Test
    void test() {
        // prepare your database
        // call the method to test
        // make assertions about the result
    }
}
```

In this testslice Spring Boot will configure all beans related to data access via JDBC. If you provide an in-memory DB (e.g. H2), it will be used automatically.

The main idea of this type of test is to prepare your database by inserting data and then use your repository beans to query them.

I wrote a [blog post](https://jschmitz.dev/2021/06/16/how_to_test_the_data_layer_of_your_spring_boot_application_with_datajpatest/) about this (okay, it's @DataJpaTest but the main idea is the same.). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, appreciate it. I will check your blog. Thanks a lot